# No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat'

Tags: android

I'm getting an error about my android project, 
`enter code here`here the error :

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat'`

Comment: Could you show us some code please ?

Comment: In your "google-services.json" file the package name will be same as your project package. After that are you facing above issue then go "build.gradle(:app)" and change you application id with your package name. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading the code from firebase. Make sure that all the dependencies and filenames are correct. Like your filename should be same as the downloaded filename.

Comment: How can I change Filename?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure that package name in your `google-services.json` file is different from your actual package name. Go to firebase and check the package name of your app and then download the `google-services.json`, paste it in your app module. This will solve your problem.